# Access router instance from my service

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I create a auth service (`src/services/auth.js`), with just functions and properties ..

```
export default {
    login() { ... }
    ...
}
```

Inside `login` function, I need to redirect user

```
router.go(redirect)
```

**How can I retrieve router instance**?

---

#### Context

In my `src/main.js` file, i create a router ..

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
import route from './routes'
const router = new VueRouter({
  history: false,
  linkActiveClass: 'active'
})
route(router)

const App = Vue.extend(require('./App.vue'))
```

In my `src/routers.js` is just map routes

```
export default function configRouter (router) {
    router.map({ .. })
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should export the `router` instance and then import it into the `auth.js` service.

Here is my workaround with some improvements:

**src/routes.js**

```js
export default {
  '/': {
    component: {...}
  },
  '/about': {
    component: {...}
  },
  ...
}
```

**src/router.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Routes from './routes'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({...})

router.map(Routes)

// export the router instance
export default router
```

**src/main.js**

```js
import Router from './router'
import App from './app'

Router.start(App, '#app')
```

**src/services/auth.js**

```js
import Router from '../router'

export default {
  login () {
    // redirect
    Router.go('path')
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it make any difference that Vue.use() will create a different instance of vue-router than the one created on the next line?

Answer (score 1):

Is your auth service a Vue component?

If so, you should be able to change routes with:

```
this.$router.go('/new/route');
```

Comment: Hey @Dan, no... my auth.js it just a  module.