# vuejs this.$route not work

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

when I send delete request to api it work well,
 but next step I want to redirct to index,
 so I use this code `this.$router.push('/');` but it not working

index.vue

```
<template>
      <div class="container">
        <p>{{ message  }}</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/create">create</a></p>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>edit</th>
            <th>delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="user in users" v-bind="user" v-bind:key="user.id">
            <td>{{ user.id  }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-warning" v-bind:href="'#/edit/'+ user.id">edit</a></td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-danger"  v-on:click="deleteUser(user)">delete</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
          <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="">Previous</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="">1</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="">Next</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    var users = [
      {id:'',name:''},
    ];
    module.exports = {
      data () {
        return {
          message:'',
          users: users
        }
      },
      created(){
        this.fetchUsers();
      },
      methods: {
        fetchUsers: function() {
          axios.get('api/users').then(response => {
            this.users = response.data.data;
          })
        },
        deleteUser: function(user) {
          axios.delete('api/users/'+user.id).then(response => {
          })
          this.$router.push('/');
        },
      }
    }
    </script>
```

index.js

```
var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: httpVueLoader('js/components/user/index.vue') },
    { path: '/create', component: httpVueLoader('js/components/user/create.vue') },
    { path: '/delete', component: httpVueLoader('js/components/user/delete.vue') },
    { path: '/edit/:id', component: httpVueLoader('js/components/user/edit.vue') },
  ],
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router:router,
    template: '<router-view></router-view>',
});

new Vue({
    el: '#foot',
    components: {
      'myfooter'   : httpVueLoader('js/components/footer.vue'),
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#head',
    components: {
      'myheader'   : httpVueLoader('js/components/header.vue'),
    }
});
```

Comment: the project is here : https://github.com/HuaYangFu/php-laravel-CRUD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the fact that I do not quite understand why you're creating multiple Vue.js instances, there is a way to accomplish this.

Instead of just creating a Vue instance with: `new Vue()`, assign it to a global variable: `var vm1 = new Vue()`. This way, you can access that Vue model via `vm1`.

```
// You probably have to assign it to the window object => window.vueApp = vueApp, because of the module bundler
var vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router:router,
    template: '<router-view></router-view>',
});

var vueFoot = new Vue({
    el: '#foot',
    components: {
      'myfooter'   : httpVueLoader('js/components/footer.vue'),
    }
});

var vueHead = new Vue({
    el: '#head',
    components: {
      'myheader'   : httpVueLoader('js/components/header.vue'),
    }
});
```

Inside one of your Vue components:

```
<script>
export default {
    // ...
    methods: {
        changeRoute() {
            vueApp.$router.push(); // 
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

I didn't tested it, but you get the idea.

**You could also import the router and call the push method on that instance. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373037/access-router-instance-from-my-service)**

I would stick with the solution from that answer and create a little helper function. Something like `redirect()`. Everytime I need to redirect the user to something, this function will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 deleteUser: function(user) {
     axios.delete('api/users/'+user.id).then(response => {
         this.$router.push({
             path: '/'
         });
     })

 }
```

You have to use a routeObject like this.
Hopefully thats all. I don't see any other errors.

UPDATE: You are using more than one vue instance. This is as far as I know not good. Header and footer should be components included into your main App. And I do not know your httpVueLoader.

Comment: Thanks you but no change

Comment: I have console.log( this.$router) that , it is not null

Comment: oh~~ no change after I remove that two instance and tag , I will keep google thanks  you