# vue-router import router from helper function

Tags: vue-router

I try to import the current router and push to a route from a utility function (where `this` is not bind).

```js
import router from '../router';


export async function logOutAccount() {
  console.log('Elvis has left the building. See you next time.');
  // Clear localstorage
  localStorage.clear();
  // redirect to home
  console.log(router); // -> function()
  router.push('/login')
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373037/access-router-instance-from-my-service
}
```

When calling the `logOutAccount` from anywhere in the application:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (intermediate value).push is not a function

This is the '../router/index.ts':

```js
export default route(function (/* { store, ssrContext } */) {
  const createHistory = process.env.SERVER
    ? createMemoryHistory
    : process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE === 'history'
    ? createWebHistory
    : createWebHashHistory;

  const Router = createRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ left: 0, top: 0 }),
    routes,

    // Leave this as is and make changes in quasar.conf.js instead!
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> vueRouterMode
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> publicPath
    history: createHistory(process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE),
  });
  Router.beforeEach((to) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !token) {
      // this route requires auth, check if logged in
      // if not, redirect to login page.
      return {
        path: '/login',
        // save the location we were at to come back later
        query: { redirect: to.fullPath },
      };
    }
  });
  return Router;
});
```

Comment: your exported router is **only** used for installation in main.js `app.use(router)`.  For actual navigation with Composition API, use the provided `useRoute` and `useRouter` functions. See the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api).